# DST temporal feature from timestamp using polars

Tags: python, datetime, dst, python-polars

I'm migrating code to polars from pandas. I have time-series data consisting of a timestamp and value column and I need to compute a bunch of features. i.e.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": pl.date_range(
        datetime(2017, 1, 1),
        datetime(2018, 1, 1),
        timedelta(minutes=15),
        time_zone="Australia/Sydney",
        time_unit="ms", eager=True),
        })
    value = np.random.normal(0, 1, len(df))
    df = df.with_columns([pl.Series(value).alias("value")])
```

I need to generate a column containing an indicator if the timestamp is standard or daylight time. I'm currently using `apply` because as far as I can see the isn't a [Temporal Expr](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/temporal.html), i.e. my current code is

```py
def dst(timestamp:datetime):
    return int(timestamp.dst().total_seconds()!=0)

df = df.with_columns(pl.struct(["timestamp"]).apply(lambda x: dst(**x)).alias("dst"))
```

(this uses a trick that effectively checks if the `tzinfo.dst(dt)` offset is zero or not)

Is there a (fast) way of doing this using `polars expressions` rather than (slow) `apply`?

Comment: It looks like perhaps a feature request to expose `dtc_offset` https://docs.rs/chrono-tz/latest/src/chrono_tz/timezone_impl.rs.html#139 via the `.dt` namespace is what is needed.

Comment: are you doing it using `apply` in pandas too, or do they have a vectorised way to do this?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity I think pandas doesn't expose the `dst` property in the `dt` namespace either

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/9629

Comment: Yeah @ignoring_gravity I didn't vectorise it in pandas either, but I've managed to vectorise all my other temporal features so this one is bugging me.

Comment: 0.18.5 was just released: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.dst_offset.html

Comment: Credits to @MarcoGorelli for implementation. Perhaps you can add it as an answer (or if somebody else wants to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `polars>=0.18.5` the following works

```
df = df.with_columns((pl.col("timestamp").dt.dst_offset()==0).cast(pl.Int32).alias("dst"))
```

Comment: [base_utc_offset](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.base_utc_offset.html#polars.Expr.dt.base_utc_offset) might also be useful in this context

Comment: That would vary between timezones though, you'd have to know what the summer/winter offset was in advance I think - which of course works if you're dealing with a single timezone but using  `dst_offset()==0` works in the general case

Comment: I meant the wider context, not just your specific application. Sorry for the confusion ;-)

Comment: Ahh right yeah I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit `strftime` for this.

```
(
    df
        .with_columns(
            dst=pl.when(pl.col('timestamp').dt.strftime("%Z").str.contains("(DT$)"))
            .then(True)
            .otherwise(False)
            )
)
```

It relies on the local time zone ending in "DT" to determine the dst status. That works here and would work for US time zones (ie EST/EDT, CST/CDT, etc) but examples that wouldn't work [are numerous](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/).

Alternatively you could use the utc offset but it's a lot more convoluted.

```
(
    df
        .with_columns(
            tzoff=pl.col('timestamp').dt.strftime("%z").cast(pl.Int64())
            )
    .join(
        df
            .select(
                tzoff=pl.col('timestamp').dt.strftime("%z").cast(pl.Int64())
                )
            .unique('tzoff')
            .sort('tzoff')
            .with_columns(
                dst=pl.lit([False, True])
                ), 
        on='tzoff')
    .drop('tzoff')
)
```

This one assumes that the timezone only has 2 offsets and that the smaller of the two is standard time and the bigger one is daylight savings.